# Convert .py to .exe including matplotlib code

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I am trying to convert this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import readTrc

path = 'C:/filepath/data.trc'
datX, datY, m = readTrc.readTrc(path)

srx, sry = pd.Series(datX * 1000), pd.Series(datY * 1000)
df = pd.concat([srx, sry], axis = 1)
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)

df.plot(grid = 1,
        linewidth = 0.5,
        figsize = (9,5),
        legend = False,
        xlim = (df.index[0] , df.index[-1]),
        xticks = [-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
plt.xlabel('Zeit in ms')
plt.ylabel('Spannung in mV')
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi = 600)
```

into an executable with cx_Freeze.

Setup.py :

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [
    cx_Freeze.Executable("read_trc.py", base = base),
    ]

build_exe_options = {"includes":["matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg"],
                     "include_files":[(matplotlib.get_data_path(), "mpl-data"),
                                      ('C:/filepath', 'data.trc')],
                     "excludes":[],
                     }
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "script",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    version = "0.0",
    description = "A basic example",
    executables = executables)
```

The conversion works but when I try to run the .exe I get this error:

[image]

Is there a way to make this work? I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 10.

I have already tried the fixes found on Stackoverflow regarding Numpy import errors but it does not seem to help.

Edit:
Thanks to comments I solved the Error. Unfortunately now I get another Error when I try to execute the converted file:

[image]

Edit2:

I tried to include tkinter in my code but it doesn't work. I have a standard python 3.6 distribution installed which should include tkinter. tkinter.test() works. I assume that there is something wrong with the tkinter.ddls import. How would I do that correctly?

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import os
import matplotlib

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll"

base = None

if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [
    cx_Freeze.Executable("plt_test.py", base = base),
    ]

include_files = [(matplotlib.get_data_path(), "mpl-data"),
                 ('C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/Nellingen/Messdaten/20180104_Zyl_NiCr_DCneg_5bar_HSC/20180104_04_Zyl_NiCr_DCneg_5bar_170kV_HSC_Firefly/C220180104_ch2_UHF00000.trc',
                  'C220180104_ch2_UHF00000.trc'),
                 (r"C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
                 r"C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll")]

build_exe_options = {"includes":["matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg"],
                     "include_files":include_files,
                     "excludes":[],
                     "packages":["numpy", "matplotlib", "pandas", 'tkinter', 'os'],
                     }
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "script",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    version = "0.0",
    description = "A basic example",
    executables = executables)
```

Output in windows console:

[image]

Comment: You should also specify the packages in the build `build_exe_options = {"packages": ["numpy", "matplotlib", "pandas"],...}`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I could resolve the `ImportError` but now I get another `ModuleNotFoundError`. Pleas see above.

Comment: Make sure you installed tkinter on your computer before building the package and then include tkinter in the packages json as suggested before. This error may have appeared due to: either your code uses tkinter or it is a dependency for another package.

Comment: I am having trouble with including tkinter. Please see above

Comment: My personal experience with cx_freeze hasn't been great. While I look for a possible solution, I suggest you try pyinstaller which has worked for me everytime.

Comment: I tried pyinstaller but it also gave me errors with the same file. And it took an insane amount of time to open the .exe. I read pyinstaller throws all dependencies into memory? At least cx_Freeze works efficiently.